# What is a finger tied with a knot or bow called?

Tags: word-request, idioms, idiom-request

What does this image represent?

[image]

I understand from context that it supposed to mean "remember" but I don't see why this icon is used for that.

Is there an idiom or saying that is connected to this image?

Comment: There is an old practice of tying a piece of string around a finger to help you to remember something. Here's an example from 1884, in a book entitled *A Modern Quixote, or My Wife's Fool of a Husband*. https://books.google.com/books?id=kR3iAAAAMAAJ&pg=PA156&dq=%22string+around+your+finger%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjj99Pvp8PPAhXBZj4KHR-7B-UQ6AEIJDAB#v=onepage&q=%22string%20around%20your%20finger%22&f=false

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it has nothing to do with the English language - it is about a picture.

Comment: Related: http://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/10441/tying-a-finger-to-help-memory-recall

Comment: I would go there to get first aid in case of smaller injuries - But why they don't use a red cross :)

Comment: Perfect example of a closed question that actually _is_ about the English language. Why is there such a rush to close things like this? I'll wager there are many on-native speakers (and more than a few native speakers) who don't understand the idiom implicit in the graphic. The OP even _asks_ about the idiom!

Comment: @P.E.Dant: Because it's not an idiom, it's a custom. Sure, it can be expressed in words, including in English, but the point has nothing at all to do with language, but with actions.

Comment: @NathanTuggy That would be persuasive if "Tie a string around your finger" were not an idiom that is described and referenced and asked about [here](http://wordwizard.com/phpbb3/viewtopic.php?f=7&t=6998) and [there.](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22Tie+a+string+around+your+finger%22+idiom+english&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8) What's the hurry? I mean, this one isn't even an edge case.

Comment: @P.E.Dant: "it can be expressed in words, including in English". But you're right, this isn't an edge case.

Comment: @NathanTuggy There are learners of English who will benefit from the question. Yes, it is more an aphorism than an idiom (although we can find sources that describe it as one), but I do think comprehension of English is involved here, even though the representation is graphical.

Comment: @NathanTuggy I can express it in words in my language (Czech) but nobody would understand what I mean, because we don't use this phrase at all, therefore I need to learn the meaning of this to understand to English language.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is used as a ***[reminder](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/reminder)***:

> - a person or thing that makes you remember a particular person, event, or situation.

[image]

The notion of [a knot used as a reminder](https://thedemolitionproject.com/2015/02/12/to-tie-a-knot-in-ones-handkerchief/) probably originates from the custom of tying a knot in the handkerchief:

> - In days gone by, gentlemen would tie a knot in their handkerchief to remind themselves there is something that should not be forgotten. Whenever they reached for their handkerchief, they would be reminded. I believe that tradition is connected with the Greek myth of Ariadne. She was the daughter of Minos and Pasiphaë who gave Theseus the thread with which he found his way out of the Minotaur’s labyrinth. I love taking photos of the threads and knots I find in the streets. Even if these knots were not made consciously by people to remember something, they might as well have been. It triggers my imagination and adds the sense of confusing navigation to the labyrinth of the city.